# Why is WebAPI action found as GET but 404 when I use POST?

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-web-api2

I have an action on my controller called GetPhotos.  When I call the action as a GET with the appropriate parms, the action is called and everything works great.  (I'm using attribute routing)

**GET Code**

```
    [Route("getphotos")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetPhotos(string userid, string password, string system, string outstation, string systemno, string version, string compid, string photono)
    {
        //Do some logic here
        return OK();
    }
```

**GET call**

```
GET http://localhost:60672/getphotos?userid=User1++&password=12345&system=UserSystem&outstation=9&systemno=3&version=6.78&compid=mycomputername&photono=003573
HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:60672
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 0
```

However, when I change the action to HttpPost and change my call to a POST call (via Fiddler), I get back a 404.

**POST Code**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("getphotos")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetPhotos(string userid, string password, string system, string outstation, string systemno, string version, string compid, string photono)
    {
        //Do some logic here
        return OK();
    }
```

**POST Call**

```
POST http://localhost:60672/getphotos HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:60672
Content-Length: 170
Pragma: no-cache

USERID=User1&PASSWORD=12345&SYSTEM=UserSystem&OUTSTATION=9&SYSTEMNO=3&VERSION=6%2E79&COMPID=mycomputername&PHOTONO=003573
```

Why am I unable to find the action with a POST?

Comment: Try changing *the name* of your POST method: `GetPhotos` => `PostPhotos`.

Comment: Have you enabled CORS ? I guess you will need to enable it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/).

Apparently, I had two things wrong.  I'm used to MVC and was trying to do things the MVC way rather than the WebAPI way.

First, I needed the [FromBody] attribute in front of my parameters since that is where I wanted the model binding to pull from.

However, it also appears that WebAPI will only allow one [FromBody] parameter for any given action.  So, what I wound up doing was creating a Model that encapsulated all my values and changed my method definition to look like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetPhotos([FromBody] GetPhotoModel model) { ... }
```

Hope this saves you from some of the same frustration!